# Apply a function multiple times in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

*Learn You a Haskell For Great Good* (section "Higher Order Functions", [subsection "Some higher-orderism is in order"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism)) describes an example function `applyTwice` that calls a function on an argument twice:

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

But i need a function that applies some function over some argument an arbitrary amount of times. For example `applyN 3 f x` would be equivalent to `f $ f $ f x`. How would i write a function of repeated application in Haskell? Please post any possible solutions, using recursion, higher-order functions or anything else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I always did something like `iterate f x !! n`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do a recursive function. The obvious case will be be when you apply the function 0 time, it will be like you don't modify the input. The recursive will come from the fact that `applyN n f x == f (applyN (n -1) f x` or because composition of function is associative   `applyN n f x == apply (n - 1) f (f x)`. The second option lead to better performance because it will be tail recursive

```
applyN :: Int n => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyN 0 _ x = x
applyN n f x = applyN (n - 1) f (f x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
applyN = (foldr (.) id.) . replicate

-->>
applyN 0 f = id
applyN 1 f = f
applyN 2 f = (f.f)
-- ...
```

Or just use iterate, as was already said before. The only real difference is that using iterate you will get an exception if you use a negative n, whereas in this solution you'd get `id`. If that's a case that can plausibly happen for your use case, you should consider which is the behavior you like better.