# Why is '2' less than 'a'?

Tags: haskell

I have two compare to chars:
'2' < 'a'. I typed this into my console and it returned true.
Why is that?

Comment: I'm curious: what did you expect to happen instead? Why?

Comment: The characters `'2'` and `'a'` are not equal, so one of them has to be less than the other (or we could simply remove the `Ord` instance for `Char`, but that would be very inconvenient). But really it's arbitrary. Representing characters by numeric codes fundamentally imposes an easy order on all characters that you can represent, but honestly you probably shouldn't worry about what that specific order is except within a few specific classes (i.e. letters obviously come in alphabetic order, digits in numeric order, but anything else is much more "just because" than anything meaningful).

Comment: The answer to this question will also be almost exactly the same in almost any programming language. Especially if you're not going beyond the ASCII character set. This isn't a weird quirk of Haskell or anything, it's a general consensus for how characters work in programming.

Answer (score 8):

Because the character `2` comes before the character `a` in the [ASCII table](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Indeed, `2`'s decimal code is 50, whereas `a`'s decimal code is 97, so the latter occurs 97 - 50 = 47 characters after the former, as demonstrated by this:

```
iterate succ '2' !! 47
```

which gives back `'a'`. [`iterate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603731/5825294) has signature `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, and guess what it does, `iterate f x` is the infinite list `[x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x)), …]`, from which we take the 47th element via `!! 47`.

Comment: `Char` represents a Unicode character, so it would be more accurate to say that the code point for `'2'` is less than the code point for `'a'`. (ASCII is just one *encoding* of a subset of the possible `Char` values.)

Answer (score 1):

Both values, `2` and `a` are of type `Char`.

```
-- GHCi

:t '2'    -- Char
:t 'a'    -- Char
```

In Haskell, a Char is a 32 bit integer. So, the question is, can we use the operator `<` to compare these integers? Yes!

```
:i Char   -- instance Ord Char -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
```

So, Haskell says that `Char` can be ordered, because it is in class `Ord`, and we can use operators like `<` to compare them.

If I go on Hoogle, the Haskell version of Google, I can see the definition of the `Ord` class, by simply typing `Ord` into the search box.

```
(<), (<=), (>), (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
max, min             :: a -> a -> a

compare x y = if x == y then EQ
              -- NB: must be '<=' not '<' to validate the
              -- above claim about the minimal things that
              -- can be defined for an instance of Ord:
              else if x <= y then LT
              else GT

x <  y = case compare x y of { LT -> True;  _ -> False }
x <= y = case compare x y of { GT -> False; _ -> True }
x >  y = case compare x y of { GT -> True;  _ -> False }
x >= y = case compare x y of { LT -> False; _ -> True }
```

`Char` is a type which is not quite UTF-32 compliant. In UTF-32, the ASCII codes are stored in the bottom 7 bits, 00 through 7F hex. In ASCII, `a` is 97 dec, 61 hex, and `2` is 50 dec, 32 hex and hence when we compare the 32 bit values, `2` is indeed less than `a`. The declared function `(<)` returns True.

Comment: It's the Unicode *code points*, independent of any particular encoding (ASCII, UTF-32, etc) that are used by the `Ord` instance for `Char`. `'2'` is U+0032 and `'a'` is U+0061, and 0x32 is less than 0x61.